# Angular Material datepicker typed value ignored

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, datepicker

Angular material datepicker ignores date when manually typed.
If I choose the date on picker modal the validator receives the right value, but when I insert it manually the validator receives null.

Stackblitz problem example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pglzxk?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html

Html

```
<mat-form-field >
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Reactive Form

```
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      
        date: new FormControl(new Date(new Date()), [DateValidator()]),
    });
```

Validator

```
    export function DateValidator(format = "dd/MM/yyyy"): any {
        return (control: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
            const val = moment(control.value, format, true);
            console.log(control.value);
            if (!val.isValid()) {
                return {invalidDate: true};
            }
            return {};
        };
    }
```